# Attach source code to tomcat's servlet-api.jar in netbeans

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, netbeans, tomcat8

I want to view the source code of `javax.servlet` package inside netbeans. My current view look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcfD8.png).

[image]

I need to see the [**source code**](https://jar-download.com/artifacts/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.1.0/source-code/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.java) (not the [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/GenericServlet.html)) inside that `Compiled Code` area.

I've downloaded the full source code as a zip file from Apache Tomcat [website](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi). When I extract it I can see separate `*.java` files for every class.

Now I need to attach it to my Apache Tomcat 8.0 as I can see the code inside the netbeans so it's easier to navigate through the code.

[image]

How can I attach the full source code in NetBeans?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the source apache-tomcat-8.0.27-src.zip in   http://archive.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.0.27/src/ unzip the .zip file and then atach the source in your .jar files.

[image]